# Create one json per one table row

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I would like to create jsons from the data in the table.
Table looks like that:

```
|code  |
+------+
|D5ABX0|
|MKT536|
|WAEX44|
```

I am using FOR JSON PATH which is nice:

```
SELECT [code]
FROM feature
FOR JSON PATH
```

but the return value of this query are three concatenated jsons in one row:

```
   |JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B              |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1  |[{"code":"D5ABX0"},{"code":"MKT536"},{"code":"WAEX44"}]|
```

I need to have each row to be a separate json, like that:

```
   |JSON_return       |
+---------------------+
1  |{"code":"D5ABX0"} |
2  |{"code":"MKT536"} |
3  |{"code":"WAEX44"} |
```

I was trying to use splitting function (CROSS APPLY) which needs to have a separator as a parameter but this is not a robust solution as the json could be more expanded or branched and this could separate not the whole json but the json inside the json:

```
;WITH split AS (
SELECT [json] = (SELECT code FROM feature FOR JSON PATH)
)
SELECT
     T.StringElement
FROM split S
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitDelimitedList([json], '},{') T
```

The output is:

```
   |StringElement     |
+---------------------+
1  |[{"code":"D5ABX0" |
2  |"code":"MKT536"   |
3  |"code":"WAEX44"}] |
```

Is there a way to force sqlserver to create one json per row?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to use as subquery to achieve this; `FOR JSON` will create a JSON string for the entire returned dataset. This should get you what you're after:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Sample (code varchar(6));
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('D5ABX0'),
       ('MKT536'),
       ('WAEX44');

SELECT (SELECT Code
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM #Sample S;
DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Comment: @Piotr Purwin You can also use `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` to get rid of square brackets.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I needed! Actually, I need this solution to have a response tracking for each element (let's say that those features is a dictionary) after sending each json to api. In some other entities where primary key is wider than only one column it may be more complex but this is very ok for me, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
  StringValue NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT  INTO #Temp
    ( StringValue )
VALUES  ( N'D5ABX0'  -- StringValue - nvarchar(100)
      ),
    ( 'MKT536' ),
    ( 'WAEX44' );


SELECT ID,'[{"code:":'''''+StringValue+'''''}]' AS JSON_return FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```