# How to convert results to a rowset of jsons with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble with this query and I'm starting to think that this isn't possible at all with SQL Server.

I have following very simple test query:

```sql
select 
    t.*
from 
    (values 
        (1, 'foo1', cast('1977-05-19' as date), cast(1 as bit) , null),
        (2, 'foo2', cast('1978-05-19' as date), cast(0 as bit), 'bar2'),
        (3, 'foo3', cast('1979-05-19' as date), null, 'bar3')) t(Id, Foo, Day, Bool, Bar)
```

And if I want to convert the results to JSON, I simply add `for json auto` at the end and I have nice JSON results as I expected:

```
[
    {"Id":1,"Foo":"foo1","Day":"1977-05-19","Bool":true},    
    {"Id":2,"Foo":"foo2","Day":"1978-05-19","Bool":false,"Bar":"bar2"},
    {"Id":3,"Foo":"foo3","Day":"1979-05-19","Bar":"bar3"}
]
```

However, I don't want to return entire JSON text blob from server, I just want the recordset of json or rows of json, where results would be something like this:

```
Rows
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Id":1,"Foo":"foo1","Day":"1977-05-19","Bool":true}
{"Id":2,"Foo":"foo2","Day":"1978-05-19","Bool":false,"Bar":"bar2"}
{"Id":3,"Foo":"foo3","Day":"1979-05-19","Bar":"bar3"}
```

Is this even possible?

I've lost entire day trying to do something trivial as this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create one json per one table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236403/create-one-json-per-one-table-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wanting to serialize rows as JSON, not a whole record set...

```sql
select [Rows] = (select t.* for json path, without_array_wrapper)
from (values
  (1, 'foo1', cast('1977-05-19' as date), cast(1 as bit) , null),
  (2, 'foo2', cast('1978-05-19' as date), cast(0 as bit), 'bar2'),
  (3, 'foo3', cast('1979-05-19' as date), null, 'bar3')
) t (Id, Foo, Day, Bool, Bar)
```

```
Rows
------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Id":1,"Foo":"foo1","Day":"1977-05-19","Bool":true}
{"Id":2,"Foo":"foo2","Day":"1978-05-19","Bool":false,"Bar":"bar2"}
{"Id":3,"Foo":"foo3","Day":"1979-05-19","Bar":"bar3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got an answer already, but I'd like to add an alternative.

To be honest: My code is not very different to the accepted answer. It just transfers the *sub-select* into the `APPLY`. The engine will work this down roughly in the same way probably...  It's more a matter of taste actually ;-)

You can use `APPLY` for any **row-wise**-action. In this case we can add a column reflecting the entire row as json simply with this:

A *mockup-scenario* to simulate a table

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(Id INT, Foo VARCHAR(100), [Day] DATE, Bool BIT, Bar VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable(Id, Foo, Day, Bool, Bar) VALUES 
        (1, 'foo1', '19770519', 1, null),
        (2, 'foo2', '19780519', 0, 'bar2'),
        (3, 'foo3', '19790519', null, 'bar3');
```

--The query will generate one JSON per row:

```
SELECT t.*
      ,TheRowAsJson
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) A(TheRowAsJson);
```

The result

```
Id  Foo     Day         Bool    Bar     TheRowAsJson
1   foo1    1977-05-19  1       NULL    {"Id":1,"Foo":"foo1","Day":"1977-05-19","Bool":true}
2   foo2    1978-05-19  0       bar2    {"Id":2,"Foo":"foo2","Day":"1978-05-19","Bool":false,"Bar":"bar2"}
3   foo3    1979-05-19  NULL    bar3    {"Id":3,"Foo":"foo3","Day":"1979-05-19","Bar":"bar3"}
```